# Spy object by Mockito in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, powermock

When I try to Spy an object in my unit test,
I got an exception.
This is my unit test file:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml" })
public class BookingSuperManTest {
    BookInfoParams bookInfoParams; 
    HttpAttributeParams httpAttributeParams;
    AbstractRequester requester;
    public void beforeStartTest(){
        bookInfoParams = Mockito.spy(new BookInfoParams());
        httpAttributeParams = Mockito.spy(new HttpAttributeParams());
    }
    @Test
    public void step1GoToHomePage() throws BookingException{
        beforeStartTest();

        requester = new Step1HomePage(bookInfoParams, httpAttributeParams);
        requester.executeRequest();

        Assert.assertNotNull(httpAttributeParams.getResponseGetRequest());
    }
}
```

I got the exception at the link assign bookInfoParams spy:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.<init>(PowerMockMaker.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:61)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:13)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:12)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:23)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<init>(MockitoCore.java:40)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:1103)
    at ive.core.test.webbot.book.vietjet.BookingSuperManTest.beforeStartTest(BookingSuperManTest.java:46)
    at ive.core.test.webbot.book.vietjet.BookingSuperManTest.step1GoToHomePage(BookingSuperManTest.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 44 more
```

This is the dependencies in my pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.44-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Maybe the version is not compatible or I missed something ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It might be problem with the dependencies. The `powermock-api-mockito` has compile time dependency on `mockito-core` version `1.10.19`, but you have also defined a dependency on version `2.0.44-beta`. This might be a classpath problem. Try removing the explicit dependency on version `2.0.44-beta`.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for hours. I tried adding cglib and objenesis but i still had the same problem. This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In the release 2.0.32-beta Mockito team moved cglib classes into [separated jar](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/248). But PowerMock still depends on classes which have been moved, so you get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

In release 1.6.2 Mockito classes was copied into PowerMock, but not all. As workaround I may suggest clone, build and add to classpath the mockito-cglib (https://github.com/mockito/mockito-cglib).

The PowerMock will have [supported](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/613) Mockito 2 API since 1.6.5 which will have been released by the end of the May, but will still use cglib. The full Mockito 2 with Bytebuddy will be supported in release after 1.6.5.

[Developer Guide for Migration to Mockito 2](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/Mockito2_maven)

Comment: @LeoLe it's solution for case, when you don't need Mockito 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use `powermock-api-mockito2` if you are using **2.x.x** version of `mockito-core` as `powermock-api-mockito` is not compatible with `mockito-core 2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the dependency of powermock-api-mockito on mockito-core  . Since powermock-api-mockito is added explicitly as dependency please remove mockito-core, this might be causing the issue