# How to Mock a static method with mockito?

Tags: java, spring

I need to mock a static method with moockito but I could not
this is my code

```
this is the class i want to mock
String buc = TrackerGenerator.getMetadataLocalThread().getIdUsuarioFinal();
```

and this is the test

```
 @Test
   public void serviceTest() {
   TrackerGenerator trackerGenerator = mock(TrackerGenerator.class);
 when(TrackerGenerator.getMetadataLocalThread().getIdUsuarioFinal()).thenReturn("0");
      TrackerGenerator.setMetadataLocalThread(new ThreadLocal<>());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since static method belongs to the class, **there is no way in Mockito to mock static methods**. However, you can use PowerMock along with Mockito framework to mock static methods.

A simple class with a static method:

```
public class Utils {

    public static boolean print(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Class test mocking static method using Mockito and PowerMock in JUnit test case:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Utils.class)
public class JUnit4PowerMockitoStaticTest{

    @Test
    public void test_static_mock_methods() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utils.class);
        when(Utils.print("Hello")).thenReturn(true);
        when(Utils.print("Wrong Message")).thenReturn(false);

        assertTrue(Utils.print("Hello"));
        assertFalse(Utils.print("Wrong Message"));

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Utils.class, atLeast(2));
        Utils.print(anyString());
    }
}
```

For more details see [this link](https://www.journaldev.com/21912/mockito-mock-static-method-powermock#mockito-mock-static-method-using-powermock).

Comment: i did what you say and throws the following error---->java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/Enhancer
 at org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl.isProxy(ProxyFrameworkImpl.java:52)
 at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getUnmockedType(WhiteboxImpl.java:1689)
 at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getType(WhiteboxImpl.java:2111)
 at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.setInternalState(WhiteboxImpl.java:33

Comment: The versions of libraries are conflicting, so Try this --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36507006/2278773